# how to use plone as a framework

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

I am creating a web app that allows people to debate topics.  I started prototyping with Django and have a functional app.  I have not yet decided on what framework to use.

I've read about Plone the app and Plone the framework.  I just can't seem to find any online documentation on using Plone as a framework.  I'm looking for a tutorial or something that will show me how to build a web app starting with Plone.  I just want to evaluate Plone before I choose my framework.

Anyone have any refs or recommendations on learning how to use Plone as a framework?

Comment: Plone is not a framework, and is only used as such as a pluggable application.   That said, it is suitable as a solution framework (application plus plugins plus customization) for two clear problem domains: intranet/extranet groupware and collboration, and various content management problems.  OP did not list the problem domain for this -- it would be good if you could clarify what kind of application you are building.

Answer (score 3):

You should start here:

http://plone.org/documentation

A really good book is:
http://www.packtpub.com/Professional-Plone-web-applications-CMS/book

Plone is build on Zope Application Server (zope.org). You should read into the zope book too. Its free.

The IRC Channel (#plone) on freenode is full of experts that are willing to help. They like to discuss with :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Plone as Framework.

Plone is an CMS. You can use it as framework,You can use Zope2 application server + Zope3 component architecture but I don't recomended to do this. Plone was designed to be a CMS so why You want use it as framework?

Why you shouldn't use Plone as framework?:

1. Plone is Slow!!! 
   30 sec. on every restart is too much. When You change something, you need restart. Autorestart(http://plone.org/products/collective.autorestart) doesn't help, you still need to restart Plone any time You change a zcml, portlet's code and sometime with python code.
2. Plone is too complex. 
   So big code base. Different coding styles (old Zope2, new component base Zope3, some parts are written with Grok).
3. You will need write xml (Generic Setup).
4. Nobody can say what you must use Archetypes, Formlib, z3c.form or Dexterity?
5. Plone doesn't have good documentation. Too much old documentation (plone.org/documentation) and there is no place where you can read what is the right way to do. The only good documentation is in Martin Aspeli's book (martinaspeli.net/plone-book) but you will need more and this book isn't open, so You will need buy it.
6. Plone has so many products but if you need really stable and quality stuff you will need write your own.
7. Plone is Slow!!! Forget test driven development.

Comment: Plone is not suitable for use as a framework. It was never intended to be. It is not, however, slow any more.

Comment: 1) and 7) are the same, you can't count these twice and as Geir said, this isn't true anymore. 2) it is not too complex...it's flexible, there's a little difference. 3) actually you don't need to write xml, you can configure nearly everything through the web and then you can export it in xml. 4) did you ask to everybody out there? 5) this is half of the truth. But Aspeli's book it's not the only book out there (though it's one of the best IMHO). 6) please point me to an omni-comprehensive software and I will give you my fortune. In conclusion, your answer lacks of cognition.

Comment: I agree Plone should not be used as a "framework."  I voted this down because most  claims are unsubstantiated FUD.  Re: #1: Plone is not slow; restart is slow, but sauna.reload makes this much faster. a/t #2: "too complex" is a value judgment -- depends on problem domain (essential vs. incidental complexity varies). #3: tiny bits for component hookups are needed, but only occasionally. #4: Use Dexterity for most new projects -- the community norm. #5: BS, see plone.org dev docs and collective docs. #6: there are good third-party add-ons, quality varies as with all add-on ecosystems. #7: FUD.

Comment: Yes, probably after 2 years Plone isn't slow anymore and finally there is working autorestart. How about mess with 3 different styles of development?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most important factor in choosing a framework is the existence of good documentation. If you can't find good docs for using plone in the way that you want without having to ask here first, that's all the "evaluation" you need.

I'd stick with Django.